# How to write software tests for a DrRacket Plugin?

Tags: racket

How does one write software tests for DrRacket plugins? Considering that a plugin is essentially a *unit* in Racket, it cannot simply be called like a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options you can use here.

1. Create a dummy unit to link with -- basically a "mock". Then test using that.
2. Use DrRacket's test infrastructure to test the whole of DrRacket with your plugin. There's not much documentation for that, but you can see the source here: https://github.com/racket/drracket/tree/master/drracket-test/tests/drracket